# Torch use of Spacy -- Strange Errors w/ Standard Dataset

Tags: nlp, pytorch, spacy

In the following code:

```
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)


SRC = Field(tokenize = tokenizer,
            init_token = '<sos>',
            eos_token = '<eos>',
            lower = True)

TRG = SRC

train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k.splits(exts = ('.en', '.en'), fields = (SRC, TRG), root='.')
```

Running this code produces the following error:

```
descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc
```

Using a debugger, I find that the error occurs at the following line (in classmethod preprocess(x) of class Field(RawField) of the Torch file 'pipeline.py'

```
if self.lower:
   x = Pipeline(six.text_type.lower)(x)
```

where indeed the arg 'x' is of type spacy.tokens.doc.Doc. But, to my surprise, when I move up the stack one step I find that the line which calls preprocess(x) is this --

```
setattr(ex, name, field.preprocess(val))
```

but in this case the type of 'val' is 'str', as required for use with 'lower' (!!??)

My code is a completely standard use case, so what am I missing??

If instead I use 'lower'=False, the code runs without error, and the Train/Test/Val data produced are correct (the train_data produces 29,000 pairs). However, if I then run --

```
SRC.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)
```

I get a vocab with only 4 items, namely:

```
Vocab stoi:
 [('<unk>', 0), ('<pad>', 1), ('<sos>', 2), ('<eos>', 3)]
```

So something is wrong here as well.

Finally, if I use tokenize='spacy' in the Field constructor, instead of passing a reference to a tokenizer function -- as I do in the code above, all of these problems disappear, except that I can only do this in a collab notebook. If I try to run with tokenize='spacy' on my machine, I get this error (vscode in Windows 10):

```
"OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory."
```

But clearly the spacy model has been downloaded since I was able to pass the corresponding tokenizer function to the same keyword arg (I checked this also with the debugger -- the tokenizer gets passed in).

I'd really like to understand what's going on . . .

(I've set SRC=TRG to simplify, but I get identical behavior if I use a language pair, e.g. SRC=en, TRG=de)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to (most of) my question:

In the code --

```
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)
```

The 'tokenizer' returned is a functional that returns a spacy 'Doc' object. The Torch constructor for Field expects a functional that returns a list of string. Adding the following to the above --

```
def spacy_tokenize(x):
    return [tok.text for tok in tokenizer(x)]
```

and passing this as the value for the 'tokenize' keyword, like so --

```
SRC = Field(tokenize = spacy_tokenize,
            tokenizer_language="en",
            init_token = '<sos>',
            eos_token = '<eos>',
            lower = True)
```

solves the problem.

However, I'm still unable to use the string 'spacy' as the value for 'tokenizer', because this relies on a symlink which sets 'en' to be a reference to the model "en_core_web_sm". I ascertained that I have permissions to set the symlink, the model install announces happily that it has set the link and one can use spacy.load('en'), but the 
Torch Field ctor still throws with, "OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory."